# Use PROC SQL to create keep list for columns

Tags: variables, select, sas

i need select colums whose names contains string '_fire'. Names can be obtained by statement select

```
proc sql;
create table x as select _name_
from work.x
where lowcase(_name_) like '%_fire'
;quit;
```

But i dont know, what to do next? I tried insert this data into variable, but then i get error: Invalid value for the KEEP option.

```
proc sql noprint;
select _name_
into :names
from work.x
where lowcase(_name_) like '%_fire';
quit;


DATA twowks1 ;
SET work.&tabulka. (KEEP =  &names. ) ;
RUN;
```

can anyone help me? Thx

Comment: Should you fix this?: `where lowcase(_name_) like '%_FIRE'` to `where lowcase(_name_) like '%_fire'`?

Comment: yeah, i put wrong code. i will edit the code in question

Comment: What does `%put &=names.;` reveal?

Comment: @Joe - Can you share some reference to that claim that `like` is case insensitive? Everything I find and attempt says the contrary.

Comment: @Nicarus You're right, i've been using SQL Server too much (where it is, most commonly, case insensitive, assuming default database structures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `separated by` in your PROC SQL query.
However, I only get your error when &Names does not exist, so is there an error with your SQL Query?

```
*To generate your error;
%symdel names;
DATA twowks1;
    SET work.&tabulka. (KEEP=&names.);
RUN;
```

Here is some that works as you're probably expecting.

```
*Works as expected;
proc sql noprint;
    select _name_ into :names separated by " "
    from work.x 
    where lowcase(_name_) like '%_fire';
quit;

DATA twowks1;
    SET work.&tabulka. (KEEP=&names.);
RUN;
```